# Numerical zeros of a nonnegative function?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $f\left(x\right)\geq 0$, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. What is the good numerical way of finding points $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that satisfies $f\left(x_{0}\right) = 0$? One way is to minimize that function, but what are the other ways?

Comment: have you looked at the standard methods of root-finding, such as Netwton's method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method  ?

Comment: No, thanks for giving me idea.

Comment: Newton's method doesn't work too well when the slope at a solution is zero.